# Confirmation Message after hitting Menu Button done in onClick event or in XML?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, xml

if I am looking for the grey confirmation bar (that goes away after a few seconds) that appears after hitting a menu item button would it be done in an onClick event in the MainActivity.java? Or would it be done in the XML? Strangely enough, the message appeared before I implemented the OnClick event. I'm guessing that it would be done in the onClick, but I have no idea what you would use to make it appear (or the exact Syntax).

`<item
        android:id="@+id/action_confirm"
        android:title="@string/action_confirm"
        app:showAsAction="withText|ifRoom"
        android:onClick="confirmPart" />`

`public void confirmPart(MenuItem Item) {
        string message = currentmessage;
        (WHAT CODE DO I NEED HERE FOR A NOTIFICATION BAR TO APPEAR AND DISAPPEAR AFTER A FEW SECONDS)
    }`

Comment: what do you mean confirmation bar? Do you mean a `toast` message?

Comment: Yup, a toast is what I mean! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First you have to create a menu item as you have one in your question. Create this xml file in `res->menu`. Name the file `main.xml`

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    <!--Change the below with your package name-->
    tools:context="com.example.mytest.MainActivity" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_confirm"
        android:onClick="confirmPart"
        android:title="@string/action_confirm"
        app:showAsAction="withText|ifRoom"/>

</menu>
```

Add this code in your `MainActivity.java` after the `onCreate` method

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        // Here ensure that xml file name main.xml is found under the res->menu folder
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_confirm) {
            //Here is where you define what happens when the menu item is clicked
            //For example I have added a Toast message
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "The message you want to display", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```